# React Axios Uncaught (in promise)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, axios

Currently I am trying to receive data from an API with Axios, which gives me an Uncaught (in promise). There is no further information in the error message.

Dashboard.tsx:

```
Axios.get("/WeatherForecast/Get").then(response => {
        console.log("success");
        console.log(response);
    }).catch((exception) => {
        console.log(exception);
    });
```

axiosConfig.ts:

```
import axios from "axios";
import { URL_API } from "./config/config";

export const configAxios = () => {
axios.defaults.baseURL = URL_API;

axios.interceptors.response.use(function (response) {
    if (response.data) {
        // return success
        if (response.data.status === 200 || response.data.status === 201) {
            return response;
        }
        // reject errors & warnings
        return Promise.reject(response);
    }

    // default fallback
    return Promise.reject(response);
}, function (error) {
    // if the server throws an error (404, 500 etc.)
    return Promise.reject(error);
});
}
```

Response in console:
[image]

Comment: Are you manually adding `status` to your responses bodies? `response.data.status` may simply not exist unless on the API it's adding property `status` to the JSON. Are you intending to instead check against the [response.status](https://axios-http.com/docs/res_schema)?

Comment: I removed `data` and used `response.status` instead. This fixed the problem for me. I don't know what I was thinking when writing this the way I did :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update your interceptor to target `response.status` instead of `response.data.status`. Per the [response schema](https://axios-http.com/docs/res_schema) `response.data` will provide you the numeric status code that you can do you conditional checks against:

```
import axios from "axios";
import { URL_API } from "./config/config";

export const configAxios = () => {
  axios.defaults.baseURL = URL_API;

  axios.interceptors.response.use(
    function (response) {
      if (response.data) {
        // return success
        if (response.status === 200 || response.status === 201) {
          return response;
        }
        // reject errors & warnings
        return Promise.reject(response);
      }

      // default fallback
      return Promise.reject(response);
    },
    function (error) {
      // if the server throws an error (404, 500 etc.)
      return Promise.reject(error);
    }
  );
};
```